# How do I check if the admin panel in django is enabled?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm writing an app which has an effect on the admin panel if it is enabled.
How can I check if it is enabled or not within a certain project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.conf import settings
if "django.contrib.admin" in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    ...
```

Comment: shouldn't it be django.contrib.admin then?

Comment: yup, it should :) Alternatively you could try look up an admin reverse_url and if it isn't successful, the admin isn't installed